# Armazendo dados em uma array em Rails

Tags: mysql, array, ruby-on-rails

Preciso armazenar dados proveniente de uma busca no banco de dados em uma array, porém com o código abaixo ele somente armazena um valor no array.

```
@busca= Item.find(:all,:conditions=>{:codigo=>params[:codigo]})
@busca.each do|buscador|
@novamatriz=Array.new
@novamatriz.append(buscador.modelo)
end
```

Comment: Poste como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solucao um pouco mais elegante. Caso `modelo` seja um valor simples (string, int):

```
@lista = Item.where(codigo: params[:codigo]).pluck(:modelo)
```

Caso seja uma associacao:

```
@lista = Item.where(codigo: params[:codigo]).map(&:modelo)
```

No ultimo caso se for associacao com uma collection e gerar o problema de n+1 voce pode usar [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes):

```
@lista = Item.includes(:modelos).where(codigo: params[:codigo]).map(&:modelo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui identificar o erro, eu estava criando um novo array toda hora. Resolvi somente tirando a criação do array da estrutura de each.

```
@busca= Item.find(:all,:conditions=>{:codigo=>params[:codigo]})
@novamatriz=Array.new
@busca.each do|buscador|
@novamatriz.append(buscador.modelo)
end
```